# Poco TCPServer does not start outside main

Tags: c++, poco, tcpserver

When i do the initialisation of the TCPServer inside of main it works, when i try to start it with the startServer() function it is not working, i mean i can not establish a connection with putty.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

```
class EchoConnection : public TCPServerConnection {
public:
EchoConnection(const StreamSocket& s)
    : TCPServerConnection(s) {}

void reply(char buffer[])
{
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    std::string myWord = "myWord\n\r";
    strcpy(buffer, myWord.c_str());
}

void run() {
    StreamSocket& ss = socket();
    try {
        char buffer[256];
        int n = ss.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        while (n > 0) {
            reply(buffer);
            ss.sendBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            n = ss.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        }
    }
    catch (Poco::Exception& exc)
    { std::cerr << "EchoConnection: " << exc.displayText() << std::endl; }
}
};

void startServer()
{
    Poco::Net::TCPServer srv(new Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactoryImpl<EchoConnection>, 8089);
    srv.start();

    SocketAddress sa("localhost", srv.socket().address().port());
    StreamSocket ss(sa);
    std::string data("hello, world");
    ss.sendBytes(data.data(), (int)data.size());
    char buffer[256] = { 0 };
    int n = ss.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    std::cout << std::string(buffer, n) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Poco::Net::TCPServer srv(new Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactoryImpl<EchoConnection>, 8089);
    srv.start();

    SocketAddress sa("localhost", srv.socket().address().port());
    StreamSocket ss(sa);
    std::string data("hello, world");
    ss.sendBytes(data.data(), (int)data.size());
    char buffer[256] = { 0 };
    int n = ss.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    std::cout << std::string(buffer, n) << std::endl;

    //  startServer(8089);

    ModuleData modData;
    modData.ModuleNumber = 1;
    modData.ModuleTypeId = 1;

    string test = modData.serialize();

    ifstream dataFile;
    dataFile.open("ModuleData.dat");
    if (dataFile.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        while (getline(dataFile, line))
        {
            cout << line << std::endl; 
        }
        dataFile.close();   
    }

    while (1)
    {

    }

    srv.stop();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to initialize it outside of `main()` actually?

Comment: There is no real need to initialize it outside main. But i would like to move it in its own cpp file. I would ike to understand where the diffrent when initialzation is done outside main.

Comment: There are no guarantees about the order initialization sequences are performed outside of `main()` and the order they're performed. That might be a reason for the behavior you observe.

Comment: If i understand it right, the tcp server runs in its own thread. Could it be that the thread is stopped when init is done outside main?

Comment: I've got some doubts that threading will initialize correctly, before the main thread of a process is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of `startServer` function `srv` object is deleted. `TCPServer` uses own thread but it finishes working in destructor of TCPServer.

Look at implementation of ~TCPServer

```
TCPServer::~TCPServer() {
try {
    stop();
    _pDispatcher->release();
...
}
```

and see `stop` method implementation

```
void TCPServer::stop() {
  if (!_stopped)
  {
      _stopped = true;    // !!
      _thread.join();     // waiting for thread 
      _pDispatcher->stop();
  }
}
```

the body of thread function is in `run` method

```
void TCPServer::run()
{
  while (!_stopped)      // this flag was set by stop method
  {
     ... // body of thread function
  }
}
```

`stop` method sets `_stopped` on true, and for this reason thread finishes working.